# How to prove if something is false or true?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, propositional-calculus

I'm a bit stuck at a task i'm working on here.

Here is the task:

Show statement "If $(P \rightarrow Q)$ and $(Q \rightarrow R)$ is true, then $(P \rightarrow R)$ is true by a counter positive-evidence

This is what i've done so far:

Since the task asks for counter positve-evidence I changed the statement to:

"If $(\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$ and $(\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot R)$ is false, then $(\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot R)$ is false.

The truth table for this statement should look like this:

[image: counter positive evidence, truth table]

How can I see if the counter positive-evidence is wether true or false? Or have I done something wrong here?

Thanks alot for help!

Comment: To use $\LaTeX$ on this site, you enclose it in dollar signs.  I did so, please check I got it right.  In particular, there are some "and"s that looked like you wanted them in text, so I left them.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, its correctly edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you need to prove the contra-positive, recall that for any implication $$ p\rightarrow q \equiv \underbrace{\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p}_{\text{contrapositive}}$$

So the contrapositive of $A$ you're needing to prove, where

$$A\equiv \text{If } (P→Q)\text{ and } (Q→R) \text{ is true,  then } (P→R)\text{ is true"}$$ is given by the proposition $B$: $$B\equiv \text{ if} \;\lnot (P \rightarrow R)\;\text{ then } \lnot[(P\rightarrow Q)\;\text{and}\; (Q\rightarrow R)]$$ which is the proposition $$\lnot (P \rightarrow R) \rightarrow \lnot[(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P)]$$

That is, you need to establish that "if $P\rightarrow Q$ is false, then $[(P\rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow R)]$ must be false."

Be careful, too, when negating an implication:

$$\lnot (P \rightarrow Q) \not\equiv (\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$$

Rather $$\lnot (P \rightarrow Q) \equiv \lnot(\lnot P \lor Q) \equiv P \land \lnot Q$$

We'll show that the contrapositive of your statement is indeed true, and hence the statement is true:

[image]

The truth table above, [generated by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28NOT%28P%20IMPLIES%20R%29%29%20IMPLIES%20NOT%5B%28P%20IMPLIES%20Q%29%20AND%20%28Q%20IMPLIES%20R%29%5D), gives evidence that the implication (the contrapositive itself) is true no matter what the truth values of $P, Q, R$: it is always true and hence is a tautology.

When constructing truth tables, it helps to do the evaluation in steps, with "sub-formulas" from the entire proposition, for example, including the antecedent and the subsequent, and evaluating each, etc. Then use the rules for the connectives to evaluate the sub-formulas, and finally, using the rule for the MAIN connective (here $\rightarrow$), evaluate the entire proposition.

Comment: If you need help with setting up or evaluating the truth table for the correct form of the contrapositive, $B$, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for great answer, I would appreciate if you could also set up the truth table.

Comment: Do you mean antecedent and consequent?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P\vee Q$, you can verify this with a truth table. Then the negation is

$$ \lnot(P \to Q)= \lnot (\lnot P \vee Q)= \lnot(\lnot P) \wedge \lnot Q = P \wedge \lnot Q.$$